# Python Atom Warning Flake8 W503 — line break before binary operator

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

The followwing code snipet gives a flakei8 Warning in Atom

```
data = ("\tDesired Int Bond:\t" + format_currency(d_int_bond)
        + "\tActual: " + format_currency(int_bond) + "\t" + action)
```

Warning
Flake8  W503 — line break before binary operator    134:13

This appears to be the correct format (putting the + at the beginning of the 2nd line rather than the end
of the first line). Why is Flake8 complaining?

Comment: This is a purely stylistic warning - but one I happen to agree with: having the trailing operator on the first line makes it much more obvious that you intended for the statement to continue to the next line (rather than you simply forgetting a close parenthesis).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. In my code I do have the + at the beginning of the second line. That seems to be what you and Flake8 are saying is correct, right? If so, why am I getting the warning?

Comment: just a guess, you're using `ignore =` in your flake8 configuration but you should be using `extend-ignore =` - the flake8 maintainer

Comment: Hello Anthony, I went into Atom/Packages, clicked on linter-flake9 2.4.0. I do not see anything showing ignore = in the Settings section. Where would I find this, and how would I change it? thx

Comment: check your [flake8 configuration](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html)